# Trigger Maven Plugin Execution if module has direct dependency on specific artifact

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Can maven trigger or skip a plugin execution if the module directly depends on another module?    For example,

- my project contains 4 children: connector, a, b, c
- a & b depend on connector, c does not

I want a & b to perform a maven-dependency-plugin extraction of connector followed by an antrun to move files around.  I want to put the execution in the parent so I define it once.

I want c to automatically skip the extraction.

Please let me know if you think this is possible and how you'd approach it.

Thanks

Peter

Comment: Can you elaborate that a little bit more cause it sounds strange? Are those projects part of a multi module build?

Comment: They are in a multi module project.  I think the answer is that this is not possible in maven and if I want it, I should organize my project to be root contains c, parent-ab with a and b children of parent-ab.  Then the logic goes into parent-ab